# SQL 2-table query results need to be concatenated

Tags: sql

My current SQL:

```
SELECT B.MESSAGENO, B.LINENO, B.LINEDATA 
  FROM BILL.MESSAGE AS B, BILL.ACTIVITYAS A
  WHERE A.MSGNO = D.MESSAGENO AND A.FUPTEAM = 'DBWB'
    AND A.ACTIVITY = 'STOPPAY' AND A.STATUS = 'WAIT'
    AND A.COMPANY = D.COMPANY

MESSAGENO   LINENO  LINEDATA
1234567     1       CHEQUE NO  : 9999999               RUN NO    : 55555
1234567     2       DATE ISSUED: 12/25/2020            AMOUNT    : 710.51                 
1234567     3       PAYEE      : LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
1234567     4       ACCOUNT NO : 12345-67890
1234567     5       USER       : USERNAME
```

there are 550 sets of 5 lines per MESSAGENO

What I am trying to figure out is how I can get something like where LINENO = 1, concatenate LINEDATA so I just get 9999999 as checkno, where LINENO = 2, concatenate LINEDATA so I get 710.51 as amount, where LINENO = 3, concatenate LINEDATA so I get LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME as payee, where LINENO = 4, concatenate LINEDATA so I get LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME as payee, and lastly, the same thing for USERNAME.

I just cannot seems to conceptualize this. Every time I try, my brain starts turning into macaroni. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So this entire thing is in one entry: `CHEQUE NO  : 9999999               RUN NO    : 55555`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @ChrisStrickland yes. each LINEDATA field is a character field of 70

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the input. It was a very good read and definitely something I need to start incorporating into my future work.

Comment: Aside from a horrible structure to work with getting your data, you have SQL listed but that is generic.  Which specific database.. Sql-Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.  And if you can change this data structure now before its too late, I would strongly consider.  Also, for the line data.  Are they FIXED POSITION values, especially check/run and date/amount?  Especially trying to parse.  If so fixed, please confirm ordinal position of the starting values might help too.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER, extracts all fields from stored strings:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e22d26866053ea6088aa78dc23c4d809

Check this fiddle.

It uses a SUBSTRING_INDEX in the internal query to split the fields at the : or by a combination of : and "  ".  I used the two spaces because I wasn't sure what your actual whitespace was, and when I copied the data out of your post it was just spaces.

Then MAX is used in the outer query to get everything on one line,  grouping by the messageNo.  Since some lines have two pieces of data to extract, a second string parser was added.  Here is the code from the fiddle, for reference.  In this case, the table test was created from the output of OP's initial query, since I didn't have enough info to build both tables and completely recreate his output.

```
SELECT MESSAGENO,
    MAX(if(LINENO = 1, extractFirst, null)) as checkNo,
    MAX(if(LINENO = 1, extractLast, null)) as runNo,
    MAX(if(LINENO = 2, extractFirst, null)) as issued,
    MAX(if(LINENO = 2, extractLast, null)) as amount,
    MAX(if(LINENO = 3, extractFirst, null)) as payee,
    MAX(if(LINENO = 4, extractFirst, null)) as accountNo,
    MAX(if(LINENO = 5, extractFirst, null)) as username

FROM (
    SELECT MESSAGENO, LINENO,
        trim(substring_index(substring_index(LINEDATA, ": ", -2), "  ", 1)) as extractFirst,
        trim(substring_index(LINEDATA, ":", -1)) as extractLast
    FROM test
) z 
GROUP BY MESSAGENO
```

Again, you will be much better off to alter your tables so that you can use simpler queries, as shown in the last fiddle.

===============================================

ORIGINAL ANSWER (demo of string parsing, suggestion for data model change)

You can achieve this with some string parsing BUT ABSOLUTELY DO NOT unless you have no choice.  The reason you are having trouble is because your data shouldn't be stored this way.

I've included a fiddle incorporating this case statement and substring_index to extract the data.  I have assumed mySQL 8 because you didn't specify SQL version.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=068a49a2c819c08018691e54bcdf91e5

```
case when LINENO = 1 then trim(substring_index(substring_index(LINEDATA, "RUN NO", 1), ":", -1))
    else trim(substring_index(LINEDATA, ":", -1)) end
  as LDATA
```

See this fiddle for the full statement.  I have just inserted the data from your join into a test table, instead of trying to recreate all your tables, since I don't have access to all the data I would need for that.  In future, set up a fiddle like this one with some representative data and the SQL version, and it will be easier for people to help you.

=========================================

I think this is a better layout for you, with all data stored as the proper type and a field defined for each one and the extra text stripped out:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11d52189b005740cdc53175466374635

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think I could've done a better job of explaining. Your first fiddle is almost what I need, except I was looking for a result like your second fiddle's result, where each LINEDATA concatenated would be in its own column. I'm going to play around with CASEs and perhaps I will stumble upon the solution. Thank you again sir! Very illuminating.

Comment: I don't think you're using concatenated correctly.  So you need to produce something like the second fiddle?  I can adjust for that, give me just a second.